# Mock Session in Spring Boot and RestAssured

Tags: spring, authentication, testing, mocking, rest-assured

I have a web application, running with Spring Boot. Now I have to write tests with Rest Assured. 
However, for running some of them I have to be authenticated on the server. Server uses google oauth authentication. Is there any way to mock session with rest assured? 
Documentation doesn't say a lot about this and ways covered there don't help.

```
when()
      .sessionId("id here")
```

On the server side I'm using HttpSession with userId parameter inside.

Comment: You can use restito to mock authentication server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution.
RestAssured (since 3.0.0) has integration with MockMvc and session mocking could be reached through calling something like

```
given().sessionAttr("name", value)
```